# Python MySQL query format : Issue with unicode and encode

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, utf-8

I have data base that has Spanish, German etc information, I thought I figured how to handle the issue but it doesn't look like working:

Here is how I am currently handling it:

```
formatted_user_name = user_name.replace("__", " ") # this is domain related 
query_user_id = ur'''SELECT user_id from user where user_name like "  {uName}"'''.format(uName=unicode(formatted_user_name,'utf-8', errors='strict'))
self.cur2.execute(query_user_id.encode('utf-8'))
```

but I get the following error:

```
    query_user_id = ur'''SELECT user_id from user where user_name like "{uName}"'''.format(uName=unicode(formatted_user_name,'utf-8', errors='strict'))
TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported
```

My question is is the this the best way to format the queries that has strange characters?

Comment: Well, that error is because `formatted_user_name` is already `unicode` so you don't need to (and you can't) convert it to `unicode` again.

Comment: @univerio how can I avoid quotes in username like this SELECT user_id from user where user_name like "Matheus "LP"" outer quotes are for username

Comment: Instead of formatting the query yourself (which is vulnerable to SQL injection and isn't always correctly escaped), you should let the driver handle it: `cursor.execute("SELECT user_id from user where user_name like %s", (formatted_user_name,))`

Comment: @univerio thanks but tried this self.cur2.execute(query_user_id % (formatted_user_name)) still didn't work

Comment: No no you need to pass a tuple as the second argument to `cursor.execute`. Note that there's no `%` between the string and the tuple, and there's a comma right before the closing bracket. Try calling `.execute()` exactly as I wrote.

Comment: @univerio found this which was very helpful https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html thanks for all the help.